# I'm having a problem when passing a parameter in GAS x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am trying to set up two parameters for the `compare(int x, int y)` function, but when I pass them in I don't get the expected results, and when I check the registers with gdb, they don't seem to have the correct values in them.

I set up the parameters and call the function like this:

```
movl    $10, (%esp)
movl    $10, 8(%esp)
call    compare
```

And this is the function which returns 1 if `x==y` and 0 if `x!=y`

```
compare:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    (%ebp), %eax
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    jne .L28
.L29:
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L30
.L28:
    movl    $0, %eax
    jmp .L30
.L30:
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

I'm setting up both variables as 10 for testing purposes, but I'm still getting a result of 0

Comment: In the caller, second argument should be at `4(%esp)`. In the callee, If you use a frame pointer like you do, `(%ebp)` is the saved `ebp`, `4(%ebp)` is the return address and `8(%ebp)` is the first argument, `12(%ebp)` is the second one.

Comment: That worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what the state of the stack is before `ebp` is used in `compare()`.

The call to `compare()`:

```
movl    $10, (%esp)
movl    $10, 8(%esp)
call    compare
```

and pushing of `ebp` in `compare`, i.e.:

```
pushl   %ebp
```

leave the stack in the following state:

```
      Values           Address

------------------
|      10        |
------------------  <- ESP+16
|   undefined    |
------------------  <- ESP+12
|      10        |
------------------  <- ESP+8
| return address |
------------------  <- ESP+4
|   saved EBP    |
------------------  <- ESP
```

After `movl %esp, %ebp` in `compare()`, both `esp` and `ebp` have the same value.

```
movl (%ebp), %eax
movl  8(%ebp), %edx
```

Looking at the diagram above, these instructions should be instead:

```
movl   8(%ebp), %eax
movl  16(%ebp), %edx
```

Comment: Thank you for the diagram! I ended up doing exactly this but changing my numbers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jester for explaining my mistake to me.

Here is the correct implementation:

```
movl    $10, (%esp)
movl    $10, 4(%esp)
call    compare
```

Function:

```
    compare:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    12(%ebp), %edx
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    jne .L28
.L29:
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L30
.L28:
    movl    $0, %eax
    jmp .L30
.L30:
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```